# Meta data for marker size instead of colour

Tags: pgfplots

In `pgfplots`, is it possible to have meta data affect the size of markers instead of
their colour?

I am referring to the set of commands described in section 4.4.10 about
scatter plots in the `pgfplots` manual.

Here is one of the provided examples :

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot+[scatter,
samples=50,scatter src=y]
{x^3};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, by using the `scatter/@pre marker code` to adjust the value of `mark size` depending on `\pgfplotspointmetatransformed` (which by default contains the `y` value scaled to a range from 0 to 1000):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot+[
    scatter,
    scatter src=y,
    samples=40,
    scatter/@pre marker code/.append style=
        {/tikz/mark size=2+\pgfplotspointmetatransformed/300}
]
{sin(deg(x))};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Knowing, thanks to Jake's answer, where to seek, I found that the issue is treated on page 283 of the manual.