# How to keep the same mark colour when using meta data for marker size?

Tags: pgfplots

Probably an easy answer to this, but I can't get it to work, and I obviously don't understand the manual or the other answers given to similar questions here on tex.sx (see [[1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73928/meta-data-for-marker-size-instead-of-colour)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73928/meta-data-for-marker-size-instead-of-colour),[2](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/86114/github-like-punchcard-with-the-help-of-pgfplots/86115#86115), and [3](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/98646/multiple-different-meta-for-marker-color-and-marker-size)).

Basically I want to use the values of an additional column in a table to specify the size of the markers, but keeping the colour the same for each marker (e.g., a colour defined by `\definecolor{name}{rgb}{x1,x2,x3}`).

An MWE doing *almost* what I want; the size of the markers is controlled by the third column as desired, but obviously the colour as well. What do I need to change in order to keep the colour constant for all the markers?

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usetikzlibrary{plotmarks}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{temp.dat}
1   1   100
2   2   200
3   3   300
4   4   400
5   5   500
6   6   600
7   7   700
8   8   800
9   9   900
10  10  1000
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[%
width=4.5in,
height=3.5in,
scale only axis,
xmin=0,
xmax=10,
ymin=0,
ymax=10,
axis x line*=bottom,
axis y line*=left
]
\addplot[%
scatter,
only marks,
mark=*,
color=blue,
visualization depends on={\thisrowno{2} \as \perpointmarksize},
scatter/@pre marker code/.append style={/tikz/mark size=\perpointmarksize/50}] plot table[row sep=crcr]{temp.dat};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}
```

Comment: Seems like adding `scatter/use mapped color={draw=ColorX,fill=ColorY},` does the trick, but I'm not sure if this is the best solution.

Comment: Should mention that for the previous comment to work as intended, the line has to be added prior to `visualization depends on={\thisrowno{2} \as \perpointmarksize}`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The most straightforward way of letting the `scatter` style only change the size but not the colour of the marks is to add

```
scatter/@pre marker code/.style={/tikz/mark size=\pgfplotspointmeta/50},
scatter/@post marker code/.style={}
```

to the `\addplot` options. Note the use of `.style` instead of `.append style`. What happens when you load the `scatter` style is that, among other things, installs its own `@pre marker code` stuff that deals with changing the colour. By using `@pre marker code/.style`, you can overwrite that code with your own. Note that you'll also need to clear the `@post marker code` using `/.style={}` because otherwise it would contain an unmatched `\endscope`.

To be able to use the `\pgfplotspointmeta` macro for scaling the data points instead of a macro defined using `visualization depends on`, you need to set `point meta=explicit symbolic` in the `\addplot` options. This tells PGFPlots to expect a `meta` value for every data point, instead of simply using the `y` value. The `symbolic` keyword specifies that the value shouldn't be parsed and shouldn't be converted to floating point format, which would throw the standard math parser off.

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usetikzlibrary{plotmarks}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{filecontents*}{temp.dat}
1   1   100
2   2   200
3   3   300
4   4   400
5   5   500
6   6   600
7   7   700
8   8   800
9   9   900
10  10  1000
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[%
    width=4.5in,
    height=3.5in,
    scale only axis,
    xmin=0,
    xmax=10,
    ymin=0,
    ymax=10,
    axis x line*=bottom,
    axis y line*=left
]
\addplot[%
    scatter=true,
    only marks,
    mark=*,
    color=blue,
    point meta=explicit symbolic,
    scatter/@pre marker code/.style={/tikz/mark size=\pgfplotspointmeta/50},
    scatter/@post marker code/.style={}
] table [meta index=2] {temp.dat};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. It seems a lot less complex than the method I tried.

Comment: I used your code for simple minimal example, and in the answer to my question it was found that this code lacks `\usepackage{filecontents}`. Maybe you want to correct it ;)
http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/301047/44467

Comment: @faekynn: thanks for the heads up. However, the `filecontents` package is only needed if you want to overwrite the file on the system. The `filecontents` environment also works without loading the package.